Run a Worksheet_Change function when the value of cell $O$2 changes
I need to run a macro when the value in cell $O$2 changes.
I have a workbook with 100+ sheets each tracking an individual work ticket.  Each sheet is exactly the same (except for work notes).  I want to run a macro named, "Insert_NEW" when I hit ENTER and the cell value of $O$2 changes versus manually clicking a button to run the macro 100+ times a day.  I know I'm overlooking something simple, but I've spent almost 4 hours trying to add this feature when it can probably be resolved in 1-2 minutes.  The goal is to embed the updated script between the EnableEvent update true/false.  Thank you in advance for any assistance.
I have this existing script:
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 15 Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Cells(Target.Row, 27).Value = Date + Time
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub

I'm trying to add the script below to run the existing functional macro named "Insert_NEW".
    If Target.Address = "$O$2" Then
        Call Insert_NEW
    End If

I've also tried
    If Not Intersect(target, Range("$O$2") Is Nothing Then
        Call Insert_NEW
    End If

@TimWilliams - This is what I added as a module after removing the private subs from the rest of the workbook:
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 15 Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Cells(Target.Row, 27).Value = Date + Time
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("$O$2")) Is Nothing Then
        Call Insert_NEW
    End If
End Sub


Does cell O2 contain a formula?

How exactly did you try adding the new code?

What exactly is happening or not happening when you change the value in O2 and how does it differ from what you expect?   If you want to captire a change in any sheet in the workbook you can put code in the ThisWorkbook module ---> Workbook_SheetChange  event.  Then you don't have to add the same code to 100 sheet code modules.

@BigBen - No, I copy / paste information from emails.  Then I hit enter, then I click the "Insert New" macro button.

@Norie - I go into the Developer tab and edit the script and save the edit.  I tried the two items listed in my post, but when I update cell O2 and hit enter, the "Insert_New" macro doesn't run.

Make sure the code is in the worksheet module and events are turned on - in the Immediate pane type ? Application.EnableEvents and hit enter: you should see True as the output.

@Tim Williams - Each of these scripts was attached to each sheet in the MS Excel Objects.  I saved as a test copy and deleted all but a couple of sheets and cleared the private subs.  Then I created a new module and copied and pasted both scripts and saved, updated the O2 value, hit enter, and nothing happened.

@TimWilliams This is what I have in the module.: (see edit in original post).

That's not what I was referring to though.  Your code will not run at all if events are not turned on,.

"This is what I added as a module" - that code belongs in a worksheet code module: is that what you meant?

This works for me, in the worksheet code module for a single sheet:
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim c As Range
    
    Set c = Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("O2"))
    
    If Not c Is Nothing Then 'was O2 updated?
        MsgBox "O2 changed"
        Insert_NEW Me  'pass worksheet to your sub
    End If
End Sub

If you want to track changes to O2 on any sheet in the workbook, remove any existing Worksheet_Change code from individual worksheet modules, and add this code in the ThisWorkbook code module:
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim c As Range
    
    Set c = Application.Intersect(Target, Sh.Range("O2"))
    
    If Not c Is Nothing Then 'was O2 updated?
        MsgBox "O2 changed on sheet '" & Sh.Name & "'"
        Insert_NEW Sh   'pass worksheet to your sub
    End If
End Sub

Your called sub goes in a regular code module:
Sub Insert_NEW(ws as Worksheet)
    With ws
         '...do stuf with `ws`
    End With
End Sub

Make sure events are turned on: in a regular module run this -
Sub EventsOn
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End sub


Tim, I'm not 100% sure what to do with your comment - Your code will not run at all if events are not turned on,.  I deleted the private subs from the sheets and modules, then added the script for a single sheet into the Excel Objects. It tried to work but gives me a compile error, expected variable or procedure not module for "Insert_New", which is highlighted.  Insert new is a module, so I copied the name from the first line of the module to make sure I didn't have a typo, but no luck.  I deleted this script from the sheet and tried inserting a new module and added the code, saved, and

updated O2 and nothing happens.  The events may be an issue?

See added edit above - first make sure events are enabled.

Events are enabled.  The script for the individual page/object works after I corrected the module name to Insert_NEW.Insert_NEW.  I don't understand why it's listed twice, but it works.  I would prefer the script as a module versus an object in ~150+ sheets unless it doesn't matter.  I wasn't able to get the module script working when I replaced the msgbox with the call Insert_NEW.Insert_NEW command.  Would this be a separate module from the private sub at the top of my original comment which is currently an object in every sheet? Or would it be OK to next the new after the End If in the first

What code is in Insert_NEW ?

It's an extremely long recorded macro from around 2010 when YouTube university didn't exist for Excel in a user-friendly manner.  In short, It inserts a new row 7, adds the date to A7, copies the info from 02 to B7, adds an N+1 loop number highlighted in green several columns over and sorts by this number/green highlight so the newest entry is at the bottom.  Since it is a recorded macro a great deal of it is the superfluous stuff Excel adds for colors and fonts etc.  I have another script that I had help with that takes info from each sheet and it rebuilds the summary page from blank.

So as long as the sheet you're intending to have Insert_NEW act on is the ActiveSheet it should work?    If you're having problems there's no real way for us to know what's going on without more detail.

Good morning Tim.  I've tested/used this script for a week or so and it's helped beyond what I originally planned.  Please send me a DM with information so I may send you a donation or tip for your help.  Paypal or address to send a check or something of that sort.

Thanks but no need for that - good to hear it's working out.

Thanks Tim.  At least you know your assistance was greatly appreciated if nothing else.  have a great weekend Tim.
